# ¿Cómo seleccionar las dos ultimas en un ciclo?

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver

Quería preguntar cómo seleccionar una lista de un ciclo for las dos ultimas.  Podéis ayudarme?
Estoy usando un for básico para que me seleccione solamente 2:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<2;i++){
            waitUntilElementIsVisible(operationsListLabel.get(i),EXTENDED_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,getDriver());
            waitUntilElementIsClickable(operationsListLabel.get(i),EXTENDED_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,getDriver());
            assertTrue(operationsListLabel.get(i).isDisplayed());
            actionsFillTextField(operationsListLabel.get(i),getDriver());
        }
```

¿Cómo sería el código que te permite seleccionar o pulsar las dos últimas?. Entiendo que el **for** debe ser con **size()** en lugar de 2 porque es una lista de webelement.
Espero que me podáis ayudar!
saludos!

Comment: Algo así podría funcionar for (int i = operationsListLabel.size()-2; i < operationsListLabel.size() ;i++)

Comment: ¿entiendo que quieres obtener los últimos 2 elementos de una lista? (¿tiene que ser con un for?)

Comment: debe ser un for o sentencia para sacar una lista

Comment: añadiendo for (int i = operationsListLabel.size()-2; i < operationsListLabel.size() ;i++) funciona. Gracias